# Return results a table in specific formats

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am performing a SQL challenge and having a difficult time figuring out what I'm doing wrong. The challenge exists in Jupiter Notebook and I can run the query for results, but when submitting the query to be checked to see if I get the final answer correct I get "Results do not match answer".

The Instructions and code are below;

/*
INSTRUCTIONS
Your query will need to return a table containing the columns described in the notebook,
meeting all conditions listed and using the aliases specified.

1. Online News Exhibition
   Following the changes in working habits during the COVID pandemic, your local library has
   decided it is time to make the newspaper archives available online. They are not sure what
   the response will be so they are going to trial a new system on a small set of their data.

The library database has a table articles with a record of all articles published in the newspaper.
However, the table will need some preparation before the library can use it in the new system.
They would like to focus the initial trial on articles from 2014 and 2015 only, and for just one
journalist whose ID in the database is 1754.

The final results should be sorted from earliest published date to the most recent published date.
Below are the requirements the library has given to you for the data they need.

Requirement - Unique ID of each article, where the first 4 digits represents the journalist ID.
Data Type - TEXT
Alias - article_key

Requirement - Category of the article, in uppercase. 'Food & Drink' and 'Wellness' should be collapsed into a 'Lifestyle' category.
Data Type - TEXT
Alias - category

Requirement - Headline of the article, without the subtitle that appears after the colon (:). For example, 'It Could Happen To You: A Story of SEC Overreach' becomes 'It Could Happen To You'.
Data Type - TEXT
Alias - headline

Requirement - Subtitles of the article, without the headline that appears before the colon (:). For example, 'It Could Happen to You: A Story of SEC Overreach' becomes 'A Story of SEC Overreach'. In cases where a headline does not have a subtitle, the missing value should read ‘None’.
Data Type - TEXT
Alias - subtitle

Requirement - Description of the article. The description should be reduced to the first sentence, up to and including the first period (.) from the short_description column.
Data Type - TEXT
Alias - description

Requirement - Keywords of the article. Multiple keywords will be seperated with a dash (-). If the keyword is missing, the value should read ‘Unknown’.
Data Type - TEXT
Alias - keywords

Requirement - Date the article was published. The data should be displayed in the format resembling the following: ‘Aug 13, 1995’.
Data Type - TEXT
Alias - publish_date

*/
%%sql
postgresql:///articles

```
SELECT

CAST(article_key as TEXT) article_key

,CAST(UPPER(CASE
       WHEN category IN ('FOOD & DRINK','WELLNESS') THEN 'LIFESTYLE'
       ELSE category
       END) as TEXT) category

,CAST(CASE
    WHEN headline LIKE '%:%' THEN LEFT(headline,STRPOS(headline,':')-1) 
    ELSE headline
    END as TEXT) headline

,CAST(CASE
    WHEN headline LIKE '%:%' THEN RIGHT(headline,CHAR_LENGTH(headline)-STRPOS(headline,':')) 
    ELSE 'None'
    END as TEXT) subtitle

,CAST(LEFT(short_description,STRPOS(short_description,'.')) as TEXT) description

,CAST(CASE
    WHEN keywords LIKE 'None' THEN 'Unknown'
    ELSE keywords
    END as TEXT) keywords

,CAST(TO_CHAR(release_date::date,'Mon dd, yyyy') as TEXT) publish_date

FROM articles

WHERE 
LEFT(article_key,4) LIKE '1754'
AND (LEFT(release_date,4) LIKE '2014' OR LEFT(release_date,4) LIKE '2015')

ORDER BY release_date
```

Comment: Your db is either MySql **or** SQL-Server **or** PostgreSQL

Comment: Functions TO_CHAR and CHAR_LENGTH do not exist in tsql, so you are obviously not using SQL Server.

Comment: PostgreSQL - the verbiage makes me curious if the intent isn't to run a query but to build a table from scratch although it's not specifically called out.

Answer (score 1):

this will do the trick, just changed few lines;

```
SELECT

CAST(article_key as TEXT) article_key

,CAST(UPPER(CASE
       WHEN category IN ('FOOD & DRINK','WELLNESS') THEN 'LIFESTYLE'
       ELSE category
       END) as TEXT) category

,CAST(CASE
    WHEN headline LIKE '%:%' THEN LEFT(headline,STRPOS(headline,':')-1) 
    ELSE headline
    END as TEXT) headline

,CAST(CASE
    WHEN headline LIKE '%:%' THEN RIGHT(headline,CHAR_LENGTH(headline)-STRPOS(headline,':')) 
    ELSE 'None'
    END as TEXT) subtitle

,CAST(LEFT(short_description,STRPOS(short_description,'.')) as TEXT) description

,case when coalesce(keywords,'') in ('', 'None') then 'Unknown' else keywords end as keywords

,CAST(TO_CHAR(release_date::date,'Mon dd, yyyy') as TEXT) publish_date

FROM articles
WHERE 1=1
AND LEFT(article_key,4) = '1754'
AND LEFT(release_date,4) in ('2014','2015')
ORDER BY release_date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CAST(article_key AS TEXT) as article_key,
    CASE 
        WHEN category = 'FOOD & DRINK' or category = 'WELLNESS' 
        THEN 'LIFESTYLE' 
        ELSE category
        END as category,
    CASE 
        WHEN headline NOT LIKE '%:%' THEN headline
        ELSE TRIM(SUBSTRING(headline,0,STRPOS(headline,':'))) 
        END as headline,
    CASE
        WHEN headline NOT LIKE '%:%' THEN 'None'
        ELSE TRIM(SUBSTRING(headline, STRPOS(headline,':') + 1))
        END as subtitle,
    TRIM(SUBSTRING(short_description,0,STRPOS(short_description,'.')+ 1)) as description,
    CASE
        WHEN keywords IS NULL
        THEN 'Unknown'
        ELSE keywords
        END AS keywords,
    to_char(to_date(release_date, 'YYYY MM DD'), 'Mon DD, YYYY') as publish_date
FROM articles
WHERE SUBSTRING(article_key, 1, 4) = '1754'
    AND (release_date LIKE '%2014%' or release_date LIKE '%2015%')
ORDER BY release_date
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).